# I2C driver porting issue

Tags: embedded, serial-communication, i2c

I'm porting an I2C driver from Atmel AVR32 U3 to an Energy Micro EFM32GG Cortex-M3 device.
The driver uses the Atmel BSP for communicating with the I2C bus, providing it with the address of the slave device, the register address, and the data.

The Energy Micro BSP doesn't implement the  register address.
My question is, according to the standard I2C protocol, can I just add the register address as the first byte of the data sent?

Comment: You should specify exactly what processor you are using.  You are probably correct that you can just put the address at the start of your data.  But the usage model should be very clearly spelled out in the user manual for your processor.

Comment: @TJD it's ARM cortex M3 - EFM32 Giant Gecko

Comment: @Mellowcandle:  In the question rather than a comment - I edited it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the I<sup>2</sup>C protocol is standardised, I<sup>2</sup>C peripheral devices are not likley to be identical (or even similar) between different vendors.  While it might be useful to retain the API from your Atmel implementation - for portability of your application code - you will likley have to change the underlying implementation entirely.

The [reference manual](http://cdn.energymicro.com/dl/devices/pdf/d0053_efm32gg_reference_manual.pdf) for your part will describe in detail the register interface and hardware operation of its I<sup>2</sup>C peripheral.  You will see that it bears little relation to the corresponding Atmel peripheral other than similarities due to the I<sup>2</sup>C protocol itself. Moreover the implementation of DMA will differ between the parts, so the driver will differ there also.

Energy Micro have an [application note on I<sup>2</sup>C](http://cdn.energymicro.com/dl/an/pdf/an0011_efm32_i2c.pdf) operation with [C source code](http://cdn.energymicro.com/dl/an/zip/an0011_efm32_i2c.zip).  That is where you should probably start.